# How to get the child element data in a single string using xQuery

Tags: xquery, osb

Below is the useCase

Input xml

```
<ns1:InvAdjRMS xmlns:ns1="www.thesourcethe.org">
  <ns1:FHEAD_Root>
    <ns1:FHEAD>FHEAD</ns1:FHEAD>
    <ns1:Lineid>0000000001</ns1:Lineid>
  </ns1:FHEAD_Root>
  <ns1:INADJ_Root>
    <ns1:INADJ>INADJ</ns1:INADJ>
    <ns1:Lineid>0000000003</ns1:Lineid>
  </ns1:INADJ_Root>
  <ns1:INADJ_Root>
    <ns1:INADJ>INADJ</ns1:INADJ>
    <ns1:Lineid>0000000004</ns1:Lineid>
  </ns1:INADJ_Root>
</ns1:InvAdjRMS>
```

Output String

```
FHEAD000000000120230803133049
INADJ0000000003
INADJ0000000004
```

how to achieve this using xQuery

I tried using concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear where the `20230803133049` comes from; the following

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';
declare option output:item-separator '&#10;';

/*/*/string-join(*)
```

would give you

```
FHEAD0000000001
INADJ0000000003
INADJ0000000004
```